# Azure SQL Convert "Time zone display name" to "Time zone ID"

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-sql-server, azure-sql

I am working with the latest version of Azure SQL. I have a series of `Time zone display name` and want to convert those into `Time zone ID`. I know SQL server contains both the display name and the id. `sys.time_zone_info` has all the `Time zone ID`, but commands like `CURRENT_TIMEZONE ()` output `Time zone display name`. What I am hoping for is a simple function that takes a string `Time zone display name` and returns the `Time zone ID` that name maps to, but I can't find any reference to that. And I can't find a table that actually stores the mapping.

Reference - [Time zones in Azure SQL Managed Instance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/managed-instance/timezones-overview)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `sys.time_zone_info`, the name *is* the ID. Not the greatest for normalization purposes.

If you're using this to have your own internal time zone list for your application, then I think Joseph Xu has the correct answer.

If you're using this for queries against Azure SQL expecting time zone localization, bear in mind that, according to Azure SQL documentation, the database operates in `UTC`, and CURRENT_TIMEZONE_ID() will return `UTC` always.

Comment: Nice walkthrough @WaitingForGuacamole, +10 from me.

Comment: In the end, I had to create a table to do the transition as expected. I was hoping someone would know some cheeky function that would allow me to get from like "(UTC-05:00) Chetumal", to "Eastern Standard Time (Mexico)" where the latter is the id used in `sys.time_zone_info`

Answer (score 1):

I think we can create a table to store the infos with two columns `Time zone ID` and `Time zone display name`. Then create a stored procedure to query that, input `Time zone display name` return `Time zone ID`.

Answer (score 0):

As I know, SQL Azure does not provide tables to convert from `Time Zone ID` to `Time Zone display name`. I think there is not any table with that information because the `sys.time_zone_info` system view [obtains the information from internal functions](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/261049/t-sql-query-to-show-table-definition-of-sys-time-zone-info) instead of other tables you can check.

You may use some tables and functions from the [T-SQL Toolbox](https://www.sqlshack.com/solve-time-zone-gmt-and-utc-problems-using-the-t-sql-toolbox-database/) or you may create your own tables.

### Using a custom table

You may obtain (and/or modify) the code to create the tables from the [TSqlToolbox](https://gitlab.com/Kittell-Projects/t-sql-toolbox/-/blob/master/TSqlToolbox-EN-US.sql). This code creates a table `DateTimeUtil.Timezone` with the desired information.

I made an example you may try in [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=fb7ed914fc1db8db2605ede6094f2e72)

```
SELECT identifier 
  FROM [TimeZone]
 WHERE [TimeZone].[DisplayName] = '(UTC-08: 00) Baja California'
```

```
| Identifier                       |
|----------------------------------|
| Pacific Standard Time (Mexico)   |
```